# How do I add images to servicenow?

Tags: servicenow

I want to upload images to ServiceNow as a developer. The images I want to upload are below. I can't find an images or upload attachment section. I don't have access to any databases at the moment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldNX.png)

1. [image]
2. [image: sample image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a table called `db_image`
You can navigate to that `table` and add an image.

It's very simple.
Please find my screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method for UI Builder-
Filter on 'image' in SN
Find and click the listing for just Images
Click the 'New' button (usually upper right)
Click 'Choose File' to browse to your file location
Upload as directed. Make a note of the <imgsrc.... line (can copy it but just need the pathname)

Then, to add it to your app, open the application experience in UI Builder
Click 'Components' on the left
Search for 'Image'
Click and drag the image icon to where your image will be placed
Configure by adding your file pathname. Make sure you use a '/' to start, then add the path name from when you uploaded your image file. I copied the entire thing so I just deleted what I didn't need, like width and height
Update your file